# EclipseLink Native API not working with SQLserver

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, eclipselink

In our Struts2-Spring application we are using the follwoing lines of code access the procedure

```
ServerSession serverSession = null;
ClientSession cSession = null;

            serverSession = (ServerSession) SessionManager.getManager().getSession("db_session"); 
            cSession =serverSession .acquireClientSession();

            StoredProcedureCall call = new StoredProcedureCall();
            call.setProcedureName("usp_list_dept_users");
            call.addNamedArgumentValue("p_user_id", user_id);
            call.useNamedCursorOutputAsResultSet("RCT1");
            List<DatabaseRecord> list = cSession.executeSelectingCall(call);
            ListIterator<DatabaseRecord> litr = list.listIterator();
--------------
-------------
-------------
```

This code is working for oracle db. But the same code not working when connecting SQLserver db

```
List<DatabaseRecord> list = cSession.executeSelectingCall(call);
```

throws `nullpointerexception`

following is the Session.xml contents used to connect SQLserver

```
<session xsi:type="server-session">
      <name>db_session</name>
      <event-listener-classes/>
      <logging xsi:type="toplink-log"/>

      <login xsi:type="database-login">
         <platform-class>org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLServerPlatform</platform-class>
         <user-name>sa</user-name>
         <password>testpwd</password>
         <sequencing>
            <default-sequence xsi:type="native-sequence">
               <name>Native</name>
            </default-sequence>
         </sequencing>
         <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
         <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.12.7:1433;databaseName=stdentlist</connection-url>
      </login>
      <connection-pools>
         <read-connection-pool>
            <name>ReadConnectionPool</name>
         </read-connection-pool>
         <write-connection-pool>
            <name>default</name>
         </write-connection-pool>
      </connection-pools>
      <connection-policy/>
   </session>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace would help, but, stored procedure are very database specific.

> call.useNamedCursorOutputAsResultSet("RCT1");

This does not make sense on SQL Server as it does not have cursor output parameters, I assume your stored procedure definition is very different on SQL Server, so you will need a different call.  SQL Server can return result sets from stored procedures, so probably just remove the cursored out.

Also ensure that the stored procedure exists in the database.

Comment: yeah it works. Thanks. still don't know why all the problem comes(exception) on another line.